# Angular managing routes with domain prefix

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

Say I have a website `https://example.com` and I want to have a domain prefix for the blog area like this: `https://blog.example.com`. How could you manage the routing for this with angular?

Answer (score 1):

it's not the same app, routing is made to navigate within the same app.

You should use href property like this:

```
<a [href]="{{blogUrl}}">https://blog.example.com</a>
```